# Time series with positive and negative values not displayed

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When I am using highstocks "Stockcharts" type to display a time series which has both positive and negative values, the serie is present but invisible. There are so many options in the API that I do not get which one enables to display positive and negative values ... did anyone encountered the same issue?

Here is a base of work:

```
<html>
    <head>

        // importing jquery, underscore.js, highstocks.js, moment.js
        <script>

        $(function(){
            dates = _.map([1,2,3,4,5,6], function(x){return moment().subtract(x, 'days').toDate();});
            values = [-1,1,0.1,0.2,-0.5,0.7]

            data = _.zip(dates, values);
            console.log(data);


            $('#graph').highcharts('StockChart',{
                title: {text: ''},
                series:[{
                    name: 'data',
                    data: data
                }]
            });

        })

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='graph'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Edit:**

Result of `console.log(data);`

```
# with moment().subtract(x, 'days').toDate().valueOf();
# or moment().subtract(x, 'days').valueOf();
Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2]]
   0: Array[2]
     0: 1446978478855
     1: -1
     length: 2
     __proto__: Array[0]
   1: Array[2]
     0: 1446892078856
     1: 1
     length: 2

# moment().subtract(x, 'days').toDate();
[Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2]]
  0: Array[2]
    0: Sun Nov 08 2015 11:32:52 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)
    1: -1
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array[0]
  1: Array[2]
    0: Sat Nov 07 2015 11:32:52 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)
    1: 1
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array[0]
```

Comment: Simple demo works fine, see: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/data-grouping - could you setup jsfiddle issue with that issue? It should work without any extra options to be set.

Comment: @Pawel , thank you, I tried to reproduce a small example, without success ... I joined the code in the question!

Comment: Problem is that `moment.toDate()` return Date object, while `x`'s in data should be timestamp. Try to use `moment.valueOf()`.

Comment: I do not really get it, by changing `moment().subtract(x, 'days').toDate()` to  `moment().subtract(x, 'days').valueOf()`, the plot is not displayed ...

Comment: I'm not an expert in moment.js but shouldn't be `moment().subtract(...).toDate().valueOf();` ? Or `+ moment().subtract(...).toDate();`? Also, could you show your output from `console.log(data);`?

Comment: Hum ok finally I am using `dates = _.map(['2015-01-01','2015-01-02','2015-01-03','2015-01-04','2015-01-05','2015-01-06'], function(x){return moment(x);});` and this works since a moment object is needed by `Highstocks`. And the series is displayed correctly through this minimal example. I dunno what's messing with my original data, I can hover thep oints on the charts (and the value is appearing, but the color is transparent for the whole curve ...cannot see it..

Comment: I'm not sure about your solution, but data with `valuesOf()` is proper for Highcharts. There may be another problem with your data - it is sorted descending, while should be ascending.

Comment: yes there was indeed a missing point in the data (I joined tow time series along an index to get the plot ...) it is purely coming from the data ...but the moment issue requires an object to be passed to the stockchart apparently .. (with the reproducing example it's easy to see the only solution with `moment(x)` works).

Comment: Ok, so in general - does it work for you? If not, could you setup jsFiddle with some static data to reproduce issue?

Comment: yes it works and I will close the question. Many thanks for your help anyway!